# Compile errors 2512 2514 2582 2819 with templates

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

i'm starting with templates and i want to code a linked list.

I have many compilation errors:

- main.cpp (40): error C2133: 'tmp': unknown size
- main.cpp (40): error C2512: 'CNode': no appropriate default constructor available
- main.cpp (42): error C2514: 'CNode': class has no constructors
- main.cpp (6): see declaration of 'CNode'
- main.cpp (44): error C2582: The 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'CNode'
- main.cpp (45): error C2819: type 'CNode' is not an 'operator ->' overloaded member
- main.cpp (6): see declaration of 'CNode'
  Did he want to use '.' instead?
- main.cpp (45): error C2232: '-> CNode  :: m_next': left operand has type 'struct'; use '.'
- main.cpp (45): fatal error C1903: Can not recover from previous errors; compilation stops

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct CNode{
    T data;
    CNode <T> * m_next;
    CNode(T d){
        data = d;
    }
    CNode(T d, CNode *n){
        data = d;
        m_next = n;
    }
};

template <class T>
class CList{
    public:
        bool find(T v);
        bool insert(T v);
        bool remove(T v);

    CNode <T>* m_head;
};
/*
template <class T>
bool CList<T>::find(T v){
    bool isFound = false;
    while( m_head->m_next != NULL){
        if( m_head->m_next.data == value)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
    */
template <class T>
bool CList<T>::insert(T v){
    CNode tmp;
    if(m_head == NULL)
        m_head = new CNode(v, NULL);
    else
        tmp = m_head;
        while( tmp->m_next != NULL){
            tmp = tmp->m_next;
            tmp->m_next = new CNode(v, NULL);
        }
    return true;
}
/*
template <class T>
bool CList<T>::remove(T v){
    while( m_head->m_next != NULL){
        if( m_head->m_next.data == value)
            m_head-> m_next = NULL;
            delete m_head;
    }
}
*/
int main(){
    CList <int>test;
    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        test.insert(i);
//      cout<<test.m_head->data<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should change your naming convention.  The 'C' prefix is used by Microsoft Library.  I suggest something not popular like 'W' or 'V'.  You should change the name of `CNode` to `SNode` because the node is a structure and not a class.

Comment: Your `SNode` constructor (with single parameter) should set the link field to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my inspection of your code:

**Consistent naming Convention**
If you are going to prefix *class* names with 'C', you need to prefix *struct* names with 'S'.

If you are prefixing data members with `m_` you should name the data field as `m_data`.

**Not all fields initialized in CNode**
Your constructor:

```
  CNode(T d)
```

Does not initialize the link field.

**Use Initialization Lists**
You could simplify your constructors by using *initialization lists*:

```
  CNode(T d)
  : data(t), m_next(NULL)
  { }
```

The two constructors can be merged into one constructor by using default parameters:

```
  CNode(T d, CNode * p_node = NULL)
  : data(t), m_next(NULL)
  { }
```

**Pointers are different than object instances**
In your `insert` method, you are assigning a pointer to `tmp`, and `tmp` is an object.
It should be:

```
SNode * p_tmp = NULL;
p_tmp = new SNode(v); // The constructor should set the link field to NULL.
if (m_head == NULL)
{
    m_head == p_tmp;
}
else
{
   SNode * p_node = m_head;
   while (p_node->m_next != NULL)
   {
      p_node = p_node->m_next;
   }
   p_node->m_next = p_tmp;
}
```

**Please review your code and look for instances where you are using an instance instead of a pointer and vice versa.**

I strongly recommend you get your list working with a static data type and then convert to templates.  This removes the added template complexity while you get your linked list working.